# Did Macs have an AV built-in and enabled by default in early 2014?

Tags: macos, security, privacy

In early 2014, would a new MacBook Air be shipped with some sort of Apple anti-virus software? And if so, would it be running by default and "block threats" on its own in some intelligent manner?

Basically, I'm asking because I'm worried that my parent's computer has had some sort of malware installed for years and recorded us speaking near it.

(It was only very recently updated heavily to the latest supported Mac OS version, having not had any major/non-automated updates for all those years.)

Comment: Why do you suspect that malware recorded your conversations?

Comment: Malware isn't interested in interested in the specifics of your life. It wants to spam you with adverts, ransom your data, or steal your credit card data. No hacker wants to listen to hours of people talking, on the off-chance there might be something useful.

Comment: I'm talking about targetted attacks for blackmail and humiliation purposes.

Comment: Then install a 3rd party antivirus/malware for a second opinion. Try Malwarebytes & Avira. Both have free versions & they will not fight each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it would ship with Apple's malware protection software.

Yes, it would be running by default, and it would work on its own without requiring user involvement.

An early 2014 MacBook Air would have shipped with Mac OS X 10.9 (Mavericks).

You can read about Apple's protections against malware that are built into macOS [here](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/security/sec469d47bd8/web). It mentions technologies such as Gatekeeper, XProtect and MRT.

Earlier versions of Gatekeeper were known as "File Quarantine". Since Mac OS X 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard) it has had automatically updated blacklists of known malware and insecure software. This means that your parent's MacBook Air with 10.9 definitely would have had that feature.